# How to use broadcastreceiver class in service class

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

In this example firstly i am starting the activity class
in that i am calling startservice() and i am getting toast of "in on create" from oncreate method of service class
And in the service class i did this coding

```
public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in on create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

public void onStart(Intent arg0, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(arg0, startId);

    }

    public void broadcastIntent(View view)
       {
          Intent intent = new Intent();
          intent.setAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
          sendBroadcast(intent);
       }
```

in the broadcast receiver class i did this

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Phone is Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("state", state);
            context.startActivity(i);

        }


    }
```

and in the manifest file i did...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>


<receiver 
            android:name="Start">

            </receiver> 
            <service 
                android:name="Run"></service>
```

Comment: So what is the problem here?

Comment: it is not displaying the toast Toast.makeText(context,"Phone is Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();.....to me when phone is ringing

Comment: Is your onReceive getting called or not?

Comment: I will come to know that when toast will display to me...."Phone is ringing"

Comment: Why you need `Service` here?

Comment: @Nun'e you are right it seems onreceive is not getting called

Comment: @GopalRao i want if toggle button is on than only the receiver must display toast to me....otherwise not –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the receiver in manifest like this...

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".Start"
        android:priority="999" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

here `android:name=".Start"` represents the class name of `BroadcastReceiver`. Here `Start` is class name of `BroadcastReceiver` whose package is equal to the package name of `Application` (package name of your app) and you are not allowed to send `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` broadcast manually

and from comments, This may help you.

```
    toggleButton
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    buttonView
                            .getContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences("app_preference",
                                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                            .putBoolean("IS_RECEIVER_ENABLED", isChecked)
                            .commit();

                }
            });
```

and in `onReceive()`

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean isEnabled = context.getSharedPreferences("app_preference",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("IS_RECEIVER_ENABLED",
                false);
        if (isEnabled) {
            // Show Toast here.
        }
    }
```

Comment: i want if toggle button is on than only the receiver must display toast to me....otherwise not

Comment: @AbhishekSuri Yes. It will not through service. because you are not authorized to send `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` broadcast manually

Comment: and to work with ToggleButton, consider using `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: so how could i get this thing that if toggle button is on than only the receiver must display toast to me....otherwise not –

Comment: i got that i am not authorized to send android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE broadcast manually bt what must i do that i want that if my togglebutton is checked and a call is in incoming state than toast  must be displayed to me

Comment: @AbhishekSuri edit your question and write code there. code in comments is not readable. and try to minimize the question...

Comment: thanks that my query is solved......could you please look over this query of mine